# Flask not staying logged in when hosting with reverse proxy

Tags: python, nginx, flask, reverse-proxy

I have  made a flask app where you can log in with an authentication code. I added this code to make sure you stay logged in, even when you left the page earlier:

```
def teacher():
    if 'authenticated' in session and session['authenticated']:

        conn = sqlite3.connect('topics.db')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('''SELECT topics.id, topics.fach, topics.topic, registrations.student_name
                        FROM topics
                        LEFT JOIN registrations ON topics.id = registrations.topic_id''')
        registrations = cursor.fetchall()
        conn.close()
        return render_template('teacher.html', registrations=registrations)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        auth_code = request.form['auth_code']
        if auth_code == 'authcode':

            session['authenticated'] = True
            conn = sqlite3.connect('topics.db')
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute('''SELECT topics.id, topics.fach, topics.topic, registrations.student_name
                            FROM topics
                            LEFT JOIN registrations ON topics.id = registrations.topic_id''')
            registrations = cursor.fetchall()
            conn.close()
            return render_template('teacher.html', registrations=registrations)
        else:
            return "Invalid authentication code"

    return render_template('auth.html')
```

That works when I host the app on my local PC but it doesn't work when I host it on my remote server and access it through a reverse proxy, I get logged out when I click on a button that temporarily redirects me to /submit and then back to /teacher.
This is my NGINX config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name domain;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;

  server_name domain;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/privkey.pem;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082/;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

}
```